# OpenDaylight Netconf notification fail for step 4 (Create the http Stream for the events)

Tags: notifications, opendaylight, netconf

As https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/netconf/en/latest/user-guide.html

I want to subscript notification for netconf devices, step3 is OK,

but step 4 fail -> Failed to lookup for module with name 'odl-device-notification'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlU8A.png)

Does anybody know the reason???

Thanks a lot.

I use karaf-0.16.3

I try step4 api, but got the response is "Failed to lookup for module with name 'odl-device-notification'"

not same as the guide shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlU8A.png